# google chrome (not webkit) print css stylesheet

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, stylesheet

Can someone point me to location of **css styles used by chrome for rendering the print version** of page? I tested on safari, webkit nightly, firefox (all updated) and chrome is the only one where if I put a **select tag**, then on its beginning and its end are **two vertical lines few pixels thick over the whole page height**.

If the select tag gets resized, the lines move with it so it must be somehow related to it, but until I can see the styles I probably will not find out.

I tried changing my print css from **media=print** to all but it was still not visible, until I select print in browser menu, then I can see it in the print preview but it already is a form of pdf so I could not "inspect element".

Any ideas?  As I said it is GoogleChrome only, not webkit nightly build nor Safari.

Comment: Remove your current css and set your print css to the only css available. You can now use the inspector.

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle that shows this phenomenon? Or if not, provide a link to the webpage the problem occurs in?

Comment: Another question, which version of Chrome and OS?

Comment: sorry to respond too late, it is Chrome under OSX, dont know version anymore, just I know it was a page with few buttons, a simple table and veery simple css linked in the page, but problem was NOT VISIBLE even if viewed by the only print css visible, it only appeared in the FILE->PRINT dialog where you could have seen the preview... before it was not visible

Comment: I'm having similar problems with Google Chrome CSS Print wierdness.  From my googling it has something to do with the Chrome PDF Viewer plugin, which I am guessing is used to generate the Chrome Print Preview.  It doesn't play well with CSS...